# Solve for $a$ in $2\left(\frac{(a-1)\log_2(a)}{2} \right)= (a+1)\log_2(\sqrt{a})$, $a>1$

Tags: calculus

> Solve for $a$ in $$2\left(\frac{(a-1)\log_2(a)}{2} \right)= (a+1)\log_2(\sqrt{a}),$$  $a>1$

I did:

\begin{align}
&2\left(\frac{(a-1)\log_2(a)}{2}\right) = (a+1)\log_2(\sqrt{a}) \\&\Leftrightarrow (a-1)\log_2(a) = (a+1)\log_2(\sqrt{a}) \\& \Leftrightarrow  \log_2(a^{a-1}) = (a+1)\log_2(\sqrt{a}) \\&\Leftrightarrow \log_2(a^{a-1}) = \log_2(\sqrt{a}^{a+1}) \\&\Leftrightarrow a^{a-1} = \sqrt{a}^{a+1} \\&\Leftrightarrow ???\end{align}

What do I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a^{a-1}=\sqrt{a}^{a+1}$$

$$a^{a-1}=a^{\frac{a+1}{2}}$$

take $\log_a$ both sides,

$$a-1=\frac{a+1}{2}$$

Can you solve the rest?

Comment: $a-1=\frac{a+1}{2} \Leftrightarrow a = \frac{a}{2}+ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{2}\Leftrightarrow a - \frac{a}{2} = \frac{3}{2} \Leftrightarrow \frac{2a-a}{2} = \frac{3}{2} \Leftrightarrow a = \frac{3}{2} \cdot 2  \Leftrightarrow a = 3$. Thanks.